# Number Format / Print f error

Tags: java, arrays, printf, double, number-formatting

I am working on an assignment for class and for some reason I cannot figure out, I'm getting an "illegal format exception" when I try to add two decimal places onto a double.  I'm assuming it has something to do with it being inside the for loop because when I use number format on other array's in a print statement I don't get an error.  Anyways, below is the code I'm getting the error on and the error I'm receiving.

Thanks for any suggestions!

**This is where I'm getting the error.  Below this is the code for the input too just in case...**

```
//Output Line 6 (the 4 doubles in reverse order separated by a space)
for(int r = 3; r >= 0; r--) {
    System.out.printf("%.2f", doubleValues[r] + " ");
}
```

**I've tried using number format with above too and get the same error.**
System.out.printf(NF.format(doubleValues[r] + " "));

```
//Input Line 2 (four doubles)
String inputValuesDbl = BR.readLine();
String values2[] = inputValuesDbl.split("\\s+");
for(int j = 0; j < values2.length; j++) {
    doubleValues[j] = Double.parseDouble(values2[j]);
}
```

**Below is the error I'm getting**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
at CST200_Lab1.main(CST200_Lab1.java:77)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%.2f` is expecting a float and you are turning `doubleValues[r]` into a string by doing this `doubleValues[r] + " "`. Try this instead:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f ", doubleValues[r]);
```

Comment: Yup, exactly as the error message said: `%f` is not compatible with `String`.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realize it was only with floats.  So to add a space in between I can just add a new print statement underneath right?  One last question if you don't mind.  Why was the number formatting not working either?  Actually this is the last question.  Should I use a different "variable" in every for loop?  i.e. (i, j, k....)

Comment: Oh ok.  I honestly didn't not see the != string part.

Comment: @user3862586 The space I put in after the `%.2f` will take care of that. The number formatting does not work with strings either.

Comment: Oh gotcha, apparently I missed that also!  Thanks a lot guys!